# How do I reference a previous column in a calculated field on a pivot table? Looking to calculate percent change

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, pivot

I have a pivot table with a bunch of columns indicating the value over time, and would like to create a calculated field showing the change over each value. How would I reference the previous (and next) column's value in the calculated field in the pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Sheets documentation, available [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), you can use the names of the previous and next fields to customize your calculated field formula.

You can use other columns to write a formula. For example, you can use `=sum(Price)/counta(Product)` where `Price` and `Product` are fields in the pivot table.

Comment: The question appears to want to refer by Column, not by Value field.

Comment: I cannot post an answer here (not enough rep) but I created a sample sheet that can solve your issue. Given Sheets limitation on that matter you cannot fully automate this, but give it a try:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P6S_Td7rlOqtMKgS9AWz_jEksfY6FaIN9no3RSsNIRQ/edit#gid=0